# Submit current selection to R from Scite

Tags: scite

I would like to submit the current selection to R instead of the entire file. 
Currently I have this in my r.properties (It submits the entire file):

command.go.*.R="C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --vanilla "$(FileNameExt)"
command.go.subsystem.*.R=0

How can I submit only what I have currently selected in Scite (on Windows)?
http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `command.input.number.filepattern`, which is explained in documentation you linked. For example:

```
command.name.10.$(file.patterns.r)=Pipe selection to R
command.mode.10.$(file.patterns.r)=subsystem:0,savebefore:no
command.10.$(file.patterns.r)="C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe"
command.input.10.$(file.patterns.r)=$(CurrentSelection)
```

It will pipe the data from current selection to `Rscript.exe`. I don't use R, so I don't know if your `Rscript.exe` tool, accepts input to be piped like that, but you probably know that already.

Comment: It works if I replace Rscript.exe by Rterm.exe and --save --quiet as options to it. It then stores the environment and loads it everytime a new line is submitted. This has two big disadvantages: (1) it is very inefficient, (2) loaded packages will be unloaded (i.e., I have to add a load() before every line of code and submit it together. Does anybody have a better approach?